# Interpolation constraint in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, interpolation

The paper "Geodesic Interpolating Splines" made the following comment on an interpolation problem:

Interpolation problem:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, let $f_1, \dots, f_N \in \mathcal{H}$, and $c_1,\dots,c_N \in \mathbb{R}$ be given.

Find $h \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\|h\|$ is minimum subject to the constraints $\langle f_i, h \rangle = c_i$ for $i=1,\dots,N$.

Comment:

It is indeed clear that the constraints are not affected if $h$ is replaced by $h + v$ where $v$ is orthogonal to all the $f_i$, so that the solution much be in fact be searched in the linear space spanned by $f_1, \dots, f_N$ and express the unknown $h$ as a linear combination $h = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i f_i$.

I understand that the interpolation constraint will remain the same if we replace $h$ by $h + v$. But, how this property implies that the solution should be searched in linear space?

Is it possible to prove their claim with the elementary level knowledge of Hilbert space?

Comment: I guess $c_1,\cdots,c_N\neq 0$ is imposed?

Comment: @JingeonAn Why?

Comment: @JingeonAn They do not mention any such conditions on $c_i$.

Comment: I think in the comment it means it's worthless to look for the solution outside of $\text{span}\{f_1,\cdots,f_N\}$ because if you find $v$ satisfying the property outside of the span, then $c_1=\cdots=c_N=0$ which is useless condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $f_i$. If $h$ satisfies the constraints, then so does $P(h)$. But, $||P(h)||\leq||h||$ with equality iff $h$ is in the span of the $f_i$. Thus, for any $h$ that satisfies the constraints outside the span, we can find an element of our Hilbert space with the smaller norm inside the span of the $f_i$.

Comment: Can I say that there may exist a $h$ that lies outside the span of $f_i$, but that $h$ would have a higher norm than the one who lie inside the span of $f_i$? Moreover, to have a $h$ in the span $f_i$, do $f_i$ should satisfy any special property?

Comment: Yes you can say that. The constraints need to be consistent. One way to guarantee this is insisting  the $f_i$ be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ denote the span of the elements $f_1,\dots,f_N$.  We know that if $h \in H$ is a solution, then the element $h + v$ must also be a solution for any $v \in V$.

However, the solution $h$ can necessarily be written in the form $h = h_1 + h_2$ with $h_1 \in U$ and $h_2 \in U^\perp$. If we take $v = -h_2$, then we see that $h_1 = h + v$ must be a solution to the interpolation problem.  In other words: if the interpolation problem has a solution $h$, then it must have a solution $h_1 \in U$.

Comment: How do you assume that $h_1 \in U$? I understand that $h \in H$ can be written as $h = h_1 + h_2$, but I can say that $h_1 \in X \subset H$ and $h_2 \in X^{\perp}$ where $X$ need not be a subset of $U$. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @hari Such an $h_1$ necessarily exists. In particular, $h_1$ is the projection of $h$ onto $U$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find minimizer $h$ outside of the $\text{span}\{f_1,\cdots,f_N\}$, then since $\langle f_i,h\rangle=0=c_i$, we have $c_1=\cdots=c_N=0$, which may be contradiction (if there exists $c_i\neq0$ given) or such $h$ does not exists (because if $\text{span}\{f_1,\cdots,f_N\}^\perp\neq\emptyset$, then take $a\in\text{span}\{f_1,\cdots,f_N\}^\perp$, and $||a/n||\rightarrow 0\in\text{span}\{f_1,\cdots,f_N\}$ satisfies the given conditions for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$), which is again a contradiction.